# Destination IPs of terraform registry and Hashicorp releases

Tags: networking, azure-devops, terraform, firewall, terraform-provider-azure

We are running a self-hosted build agent behind a corporate firewall. All outbound traffic to the internet is blocked unless the destinations IPs are allowed on the firewall.

When the `terraform init` statement is executed in the pipeline, the container instance tries to download the most recent provider packages from registry.terraform.io and releases.hashicorp.com from the Terraform/Hashicorp servers and therefore it crashes:

```
Initializing the backend...

Successfully configured the backend "azurerm"! Terraform will automatically
use this backend unless the backend configuration changes.

Initializing provider plugins...
- Finding latest version of hashicorp/time...
- Finding hashicorp/azurerm versions matching "~> 3.0"...
╷
│ Error: Failed to query available provider packages
│ 
│ Could not retrieve the list of available versions for provider
│ hashicorp/time: could not connect to registry.terraform.io: Failed to
│ request discovery document: Get
│ "https://registry.terraform.io/.well-known/terraform.json": net/http:
│ request canceled while waiting for connection (Client.Timeout exceeded
│ while awaiting headers)
╵
```

If we allow traffic to this IP for a moment, we receive the same error when it tries to install the provider:

```
Initializing provider plugins...
- Finding hashicorp/azurerm versions matching "~> 3.0"...
- Finding latest version of hashicorp/azuread...
╷
│ Error: Failed to install provider
│ 
│ Error while installing hashicorp/azurerm v3.40.0: could not query provider
│ registry for registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/azurerm: failed to retrieve
│ authentication checksums for provider: the request failed after 2 attempts,
│ please try again later: Get
│ "https://releases.hashicorp.com/terraform-provider-azurerm/3.40.0/terraform-provider-azurerm_3.40.0_SHA256SUMS":
│ net/http: request canceled while waiting for connection (Client.Timeout
│ exceeded while awaiting headers)
╵
```

We tried to manually add the IPs but they are managed dynamically and subjected to change (probably behind CDN or load balancer that masks the IPs).
We also tried to whitelist the whole FQDN (registry.terraform.io and releases.hashicorp.com) but that also did not work.

Is there someone that has dealt with a similar configuration and fixed this?
Or is there a list there somewhere a list that is kept up to date with all Terraform/Hashicorp destination IPs/Subnets/FQDNs?

Comment: Normally this is solved with a proxy or by hosting your own registry.

Answer (score 1):

> We also tried to whitelist the whole FQDN (registry.terraform.io and releases.hashicorp.com) but that also did not work.

Keep digging in that direction.

Use packet capture software (e.g. Wireshark) to see which domains are being queried for DNS requests during a `terraform init` and `terraform plan`.

Then add those to the firewall exceptions for outbound traffic.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved!

The ping to registry.terraform.io resolved to .cloudfront.net. CloudFront is a CDN of Amazon.

Palo Alto (the firewall vendor) publishes CloudFront EDLs (External Dynamic Lists) that you can find [here](https://docs.paloaltonetworks.com/resources/edl-hosting-service). After adding the EDL to the specific firewall allow rule, traffic could flow to the Terraform/HashicCorp servers and therefore, the task that executed the  `terraform init` statements finished with exitcode 0.